# limits of function two variables

Tags: calculus

Using trajectories $y=mx-m, m\neq0$ we can see that $\lim\limits_{(x,y) \to (1,0)} \frac{(x-1)^2\ln x}{(x-1)^2 + y^2}=0$. But we know that is not enough to affirm that result. You need to use the limit definition to find the relationship between $\delta $ and $\epsilon $, that's where my difficulty lies. Thanks for the help

Comment: Does $Lnx$ mean $\ln x$?

Comment: Do we really need to use first principles?

Answer (score 0):

**HINTS:**

Note that we can write

$$\frac{(x-1)^2}{(x-1)^2+y^2}\le 1$$

and

$$\frac{x-1}{x}\le \log(x)\le x-1$$

Comment: Please let me know how I can improve my answer. I really want to give you the best answer I can. -Mark